# facebookの投稿をRSS配信したい

Tags: facebook

facebookの投稿をRSS配信するために、XML？feed？を自動生成したいです。
設定がわからず困っています。

Comment: FacebookにはRSSを作成する機能は無くなったようですよ。[RSSフィード機能がなくなったFacebookページの更新情報をRSSリーダーで読む方法](https://www.momosiri.info/post-18649/) 検索するとこんな記事が何か参考になるかも。[Feed43を使ってRSS配信のないサイトの自作RSSフィードを作ろう](https://www.usjapanlifehacker.com/feed43-2/), [他人が管理しているfacebookページの更新情報をRSSで取得する（RSS-Bridge）](https://miyadir.com/1655/), [sanpii/out-of-gafam](https://github.com/sanpii/out-of-gafam)

Comment: ＞kunifさま　参考サイトURLありがとうございました。